# redux persist crash when multiple

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I'm using redux-persist in react js app.
I have 2 reducers called: auth, streams.
when I define both of them together with persistReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' 
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' 
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'

import auth  from './auth.reducer';
import stream  from './stream.reducer';

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['auth','stream'],
}
const authPersistConfig = {
    key: 'auth',
    storage: storage,
  };
const streamsPersistConfig = {
  key: 'stream',
  storage: storage,
  };





const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth:persistReducer(authPersistConfig,auth),
  stream:persistReducer(streamsPersistConfig,stream),
});

export default persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer)\
```

it crash and throw error
[image]

but when I define only one persistReducer (no matter which of them)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' 
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'

import auth  from './auth.reducer';
import stream  from './stream.reducer';

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['auth','stream'],
}
const authPersistConfig = {
    key: 'auth',
    storage: storage,
  };




const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth:persistReducer(authPersistConfig,auth),
  stream:stream
});

export default persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer)
```

it works fine and no throws any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution looks like following snippet

```
// store.js

import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import auth from './auth'
import stream from './stream'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  stream,
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  const persistor = persistStore(store)

  return { store, persistor }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it works fine.. how can I define persist store for each reducer?

Comment: @AdirZoari could you send me a console.log of the props from mapStateToProps in any one component

Comment: Yes. I send some 2 images https://ibb.co/tLDjp6S https://ibb.co/zhjRZpq

Comment: @AdirZoari could it be that the other way works also but the variable full_name ist not in user ?

Comment: it in user.. I found that the issue happen only when I do  case 'REHYDRATE' into the auth reducer.. this way https://pastebin.com/fQgLzXEL I found it in docs, not sure why it's not working.. when I print rehydrate.action there is action.payload user and token

Answer (score 0):

You can use `persistCombineReducers` from the redux-persist library
and pass the configuration object as the first parameter and then set of reducers as a single object using key value pairs as the second parameter.
See the code example given below

```
import persistCombineReducers from "redux-persist/es/persistCombineReducers";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};
  
const persistedReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, {auth:authReducer});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```